# Why am I getting a white screen while uploading a file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, mariadb

I am currently working with PHP on a web project with MVC architecture; the main task is to upload files in CSV format to a database in MariaDB. The project works without any problems, but there's a detail in which when the file is being uploaded, a blank screen is shown while it is being uploaded to the database; once the file is completely uploaded, the blank screen disappears and the interface is shown again with the respective success message that I added. Why is this happening? I don't handle large files, since with a relatively small file (8 KB) this appearance of a blank screen happens to me.

I had no problem with this detail at first, but now I want to show a .GIF image with a rotating ring so that the user knows that the upload process is taking place, but when the blank screen is displayed, I cannot find way of displaying said image. How could I stop showing the blank screen while uploading a file?

I attach my code:

**VIEW (HTML)**:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" required/>
   </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="import_file" value="IMPORT"/>
 </fieldset>

  <?php
     $excel = new ControllerEvents();
     $excel ->ctrImportExcel();
  ?>

</form>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
static public function ctrImportExcel()
{
    if(isset($_POST["import_file"])) 
    { 
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $file_open = fopen($file,"r"); 

        while(($data = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $no_empleado = $data[0];
            $date = $data[1]; 

            $table = "events";

            $answer  = ModelEvents::mdlImportExcel($table, $data);
        }

        if($answer=="ok")
        {
            echo"<script>
                Swal.fire({ 
                    title: 'Success!',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = 'index';
                        }
                    });
            </script>";
                
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>
                    Swal.fire({ 
                        title: 'Error!',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                        });
                 </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";
    class ModelEvents{

    static public function mdlImportExcel($table,$data)
    {
        $stmt = connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(employee,start_event) VALUES(:employee,:start_event)");
            
        $stmt->bindparam(":employee",$data[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(":start_event",$data[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but `$answer` is only the success of inserting the last line of the CSV. If you get errors on other lines, you won't report it to the user.

Comment: Sounds like it's just the amount of time the server takes to process the request and send back a response. And a form post always removes the current page in the browser and waits for a new one, so you might we'll see an empty space if that takes a few seconds. That's standard web behaviour since day 1. If you want avoid that, and stay on the same page and show something while the request is in progress then the first step is to switch to using AJAX to send the request.

Comment: Before the loop you could output some JS that displays something and flush.

Comment: @ADyson Actually, it's more normal to keep displaying the form until a response is received, not switch to a blank screen.

Comment: Might sound silly but try moving `<?php $excel = new ControllerEvents(); $excel ->ctrImportExcel(); ?>` to the beginning of the script. The way you have it, you have already started outputting the form again to the browser, maybe thats why it has cleared itself in preparation

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it didn't worked :(

Comment: What is `$excel = new ControllerEvents(); $excel ->ctrImportExcel();` doing in _the view_ to begin with ...?!?

Comment: @CBroe, That's how I call the controller function. Is it a bad practice? How should it be done?